# how to give .apk permission as a root user?

Tags: android, kivy, adb, logcat, buildozer

i recently made an APK file by buildozer. and it's ok when i open this application on Ubuntu, windows..but it crashes in Android.
so i debugged through `adb logcat` and found the reason why crashes.

this is `buildozer.spec`

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = TUBUC

# (str) Package name
package.name = tubuc

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,txt,atlas,ttf

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 1.0

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = hostpython2,kivy

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = /root/hi2/image/Loading_Screen.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = /root/hi2/image/logo.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 2.7

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.10.0

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 1

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,FACTORY_TEST

# (int) Android API to use
android.api = 24

# (int) Minimum API required
android.minapi = 9

# (int) Android SDK version to use
android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
android.ndk = 16b

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to stable
#p4a.branch = stable

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

adb logcat

```
08-17 01:54:14.216   839  1040 I python  : ('Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is', '__main__')
08-17 01:54:14.252   839  1040 I python  : ['/data/user/0/org.test.tubuc/files/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/data/user/0/org.test.tubuc/files/app/lib/site-python']
08-17 01:54:14.252   839  1040 I python  : AND: Ran string
08-17 01:54:14.252   839  1040 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
08-17 01:54:14.360   839  1040 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 19)
08-17 01:54:14.360   839  1040 I python  : [WARNING] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
08-17 01:54:14.366   839  1040 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/org.test.tubuc/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_18-08-17_0.txt
08-17 01:54:14.367   839  1040 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
08-17 01:54:14.367   839  1040 I python  : [INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.2 (default, Aug 14 2018, 08:46:55) 
08-17 01:54:14.367   839  1040 I python  : [GCC 4.8]
08-17 01:54:14.396   839  1040 I python  : [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
08-17 01:54:14.643   839  1040 I python  : [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
08-17 01:54:14.667   839  1040 I python  : [INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
08-17 01:54:14.713   839  1040 I python  : [INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
08-17 01:54:14.715   839  1040 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
08-17 01:54:14.730   839  1040 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
08-17 01:54:14.730   839  1040 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <gl>
08-17 01:54:14.731   839  1040 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <OpenGL ES 3.2 v1.r22p0-01rel0.f294e54ceb2cb2d81039204fa4b0402e>
08-17 01:54:14.731   839  1040 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <ARM>
08-17 01:54:14.731   839  1040 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <Mali-T880>
08-17 01:54:14.731   839  1040 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 2
08-17 01:54:14.731   839  1040 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
08-17 01:54:14.731   839  1040 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
08-17 01:54:14.753   839  1040 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
08-17 01:54:14.754   839  1040 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
08-17 01:54:14.776   839  1040 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
08-17 01:54:14.778   839  1040 I python  : [WARNING] [GL          ] Unpack subimage support is not available
08-17 01:54:15.082   839  1040 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
08-17 01:54:15.082   839  1040 I python  :    File "/root/hi2/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 73, in <module>
08-17 01:54:15.082   839  1040 I python  :    File "/root/hi2/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/tubuc/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 301, in load_file
08-17 01:54:15.082   839  1040 I python  :    File "/root/hi2/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/tubuc/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 382, in load_string
08-17 01:54:15.082   839  1040 I python  :    File "/root/hi2/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/tubuc/private/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 564, in _apply_rule
08-17 01:54:15.083   839  1040 I python  :    File "/root/hi2/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 56, in __init__
08-17 01:54:15.083   839  1040 I python  :  IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root/hi2/station/ICB164000039.txt'
08-17 01:54:15.105   839  1040 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

It is because of Permission Denied.
you can see the second line from bottom tells me Permission Denied.

so i made folder that does not need root account. but 
it gives me this log. (folder and file is clearly exist)

```
08-17 02:07:44.238  7380  7411 I python  :  IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/guk/station/ICB164000039.txt'
08-17 02:07:44.259  7380  7411 I python  : Python for android ended. this log.
```

So is there any solution for this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android you only have permission to write within your app's sandbox.  There is no home directory, you cannot make random files off of root.  The directory you write to is defined by context.getFilesDir().  There is no safe path you can assume, as the exact place apps are stored can differ by device and API level.

Comment: I wanted to use the txt file when I created apk, so I put txt file in the same directory as main.py. Is this the wrong way?

Comment: You can't use a file that exists when you create the apk inside the apk file.  Its a different computer, that file won't exist on your phone.  If you want the file to be brought along with your apk, make it an asset.

Comment: I made an asset folder, and i checked there is an assets folder in my APK file. but still same error here. 08-17 15:21:20.363  5635  5840 I python  :  IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'assets/station/ICB164000039.txt' i also tried relative path. but it was not helpful. can you give me some advice?